# Different names for model with parameters specified and not?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

Say I have a general model:
$$y=\beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{0}$$
or
$$y=\beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2}+\beta_{0}$$
I might be performing some operations to determine which **general** model to choose.

Say I have decided on a general model structure and want to define a **specialised** model, like:
$$y=5 x_{1} +2$$

What is the vocabulary to call (1) model without parameter values defined (2) model with specific parameter values (can this even be called a model, are names *function* or *equation* more appropriate)?

Comment: I've deleted the "functional equations" tag because that term in standard usage means something other than this. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficients $\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_0$ in this context are often called parameters.  Particular values of the parameters determine a particular member of a **parametrized family** of models.

In the context of linear regression, one sometimes says those three parameters are **fixed** (as opposed to random) and **unobservable**, so that they must be estimated by using least squares.  The variables $x_1,\,x_2$ are typically **observable** and often treated as **fixed** rather than **random**, even though they may change when a new sample is taken.  The rationale for treating them as not random is that one may be concerned with the **conditional** distribution of $y$, or of the least-squares estimates of the parameters, **given** the $x$-values.  On the other hand, $y$, although **observable**, would be treated as **random**.